# What is a best practice to pass data from Action to view(jsp) in Struts 1.3.?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, struts, struts-1

I am writing web application in **struts 1.3**.  I want to pass ArrayList of Employees to JSP page.

I see following two approches :

**1.**
Put List of Employee as a field into ActionForm.

```
List<Employee>  employees;
```

Action class setting this field:

```
empForm.setEmployees(employeeList);
```

And JSP using this data as :

```
${empForm.employees}
```

**2.** 
Put the list of Employees directly into request.

Action class setting employeeList into request.

```
request.setAttribute("employees", employeeList);
```

And in JSP:

```
${employees}
```

Please suggest what approach should I go with. Which one is considered to be a good practice in **Struts 1.3.**

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. If the page required form you can put the list in the ActionForm. Personally I prefer setting inside ActionForm since it is more organized.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to edit data it's better to put it to action form otherwise there is no big difference.